# nginx - client_max_body_size has no effect with no limit

Tags: http, nginx, header

In Nginx .conf file > http block with no limit

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it should work this way. What did you try? What response did you get? Any errors in the logs?

Comment: I want to upload some files and I get an Error you can not upload this size of file reason is we are not set this much value of the file.